# How to bind custom jsf-validators to programmatically created HTML Elements?

Tags: validation, jsf

I am using JSF 2.0 and want to attach my custom RangeValidator to a HtmlInputText. In my backing bean, there is a snippet which creates the HTMLInputText. If I add a default validator, my code works like expected. If I add my custom RangeValidator in the same manner (by using FacesContext...) there is an error coming up, more precisely an 'unknown id' error. If I create an instance by using the new keyword, it seems that I am not able to use my accessor-methods, more precisely it seems that my HtmlInputText will use a freshly created RangeValidator-instance at runtime, so property values are minimum = 0 and maximum = 0, my validator is useless. How can I get my custom validator working? Thanks in advance.

```
// Snippet which creates HTML-Components
if ((integerField.getMaximalValue() != null) && (integerField.getMinimalValue() != null)) { // serverside validation required
    // Default JSF Validator - works!
    // final LongRangeValidator validator = (LongRangeValidator) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().createValidator(LongRangeValidator.VALIDATOR_ID);
    // CustomValidator - ERROR: Unknown validator id; 
    final RangeValidator validator = (RangeValidator) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().createValidator("mypackage.validators.RangeValidator");
    // construct custom validator instance - not working, seems to be a different instance!
    // RangeValidator validator = new RangeValidator();
    validator.setMaximum(integerField.getMaximalValue());
    validator.setMinimum(integerField.getMinimalValue());    
    inputInteger.addValidator(validator);
}

// Validator
@FacesValidator("RangeValidator")
public class RangeValidator implements Validator {
    private int minimum;
    private int maximum;
    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent uiComponent, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        //System.out.println("RangeValidator.validate: " + value);
        int val = Integer.parseInt((String) value);
        if ((val <= this.getMaximum()) && (val >= this.getMinimum())){
            // ok
        } else {
            FacesMessage fm = new FacesMessage();
            String message = "Das Feld " + uiComponent.getClientId() + " liefert Validierungsfehler!";
            fm.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            fm.setSummary(message);
            fm.setDetail(message);
            throw new ValidatorException(fm); 
        }
    }
    // Accessors
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for the problem: RangeValidator needs to implement the Serializable-interface as well and all will work like expected;